# How to separate logs of uWSGI?

Tags: uwsgi

I want to separate the logs of uwsgi like access logs, request logs, error logs in individual files. At the moment these all are in same file and not well formatted.

Answer (score 6):

There are configuration directives to specify different loggers for requests and all other messages: `logger` and `req-logger`. Example:

```
# uwsgi.ini
req-logger = file:/var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi-req.log
logger = file:/var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi.log
```

If you want nondefault formatting, filtering or a peculiar output location, you could write your own logging plugin. Here's a link the relevant page: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Logging.html