# Route uwsgi logs by HTTP method (HEAD/GET/etc)

Tags: uwsgi

I'm using uwsgi behind nginx, monitored by monit.

Monit checks the status of the site by (by default) sending a `HEAD / HTTP/1.1` request. This works fine, but I end up with an awful lot of these lines in the logfile:

```
[pid: 28317|app: 0|req: 1/1] xxx.ip.addr.xxx () {34 vars in 366 bytes} [Wed Aug  2 16:17:58 2017] HEAD / => generated 0 bytes in 13 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 81 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

It looks like `log-route` and `log-req-route` are designed for this, see [the docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Logging.html) and [other questions on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410122/how-to-separate-logs-of-uwsgi), but I can't seem to route HEAD requests to their own file.

My uwsgi.ini:

```
# Log Monit pings separately
req-logger = monitrequests file:uwsgi-monitrequests.log                                                

# All other requests         
req-logger = file:uwsgi-requests.log

# Everything else
logger = file:uwsgi.log                     

log-req-route = monitrequests .*HEAD.*
```

All the logged requests just end up in uwsgi-requests.log.

One work-around could be to have Monit probe a health-check url (e.g. my.site/heartbeat) and have uwsgi route based on that, are there any better options?